# mysql query to group duplicate records with a different field

Tags: mysql

I have a table T1 with columns id, C1, C2 and C3. I am using the following query to find duplicate records

```
Select group_concat(id) from T1 group by C2 having count(id) >1;
```

Now I want to group all the duplicate records by column C3. How do I do it?
Note : I am not expecting

> Select group_concat(id) from T1 group by C2,C3 having count(id) >1;

I want to get all the records having duplicate values on C2 and group them only based on C3 irrespective of their C2 value

```
id C1 C2 C3

1  a  3   A

2  b  2   A

3  c  2   A

4  d  2   B

5  e  3   C
```

In the above data 1,5 are duplicate record with C2 value 3 and 2,3,4 is duplciate records with C2 value 2. I want an output

```
A - has 2 duplicates (with C2 values 2 and 3 )
B - has 1 duplicate (with C2 value 2)
C - has 1 duplicate (with C2 value 3)
```

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In a Derived Table, we can `GROUP BY` on `C2` and identify their count(s). `C2` value having count more than 1 is basically a duplicate (occurring in more than one row).
- Join this result-set to the main table on `C2`. This will help us in getting an additional column showing `C2` count against every row.
- Now, we can use conditional aggregation on `C3` using [`COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count), considering those cases where count is more than 1.

Try:

```
SELECT 
  t.C3, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(dt.count_C2 > 1, t.C2, NULL)) AS duplicates 
FROM 
  your_table AS t 
JOIN
(
  SELECT
    C2,
    COUNT(id) AS count_C2
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY C2
) AS dt
  ON dt.C2 = t.C2 
GROUP BY t.C3
```

---

**Result**

```
| C3  | duplicates |
| --- | ---------- |
| A   | 2          |
| B   | 1          |
| C   | 1          |
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m6vUfS8MiFM2aTAuby5zk1/0)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM T1
WHERE C2 IN
(    
  SELECT C2
  FROM T1
  GROUP BY C2
  HAVING COUNT(id)>1
)
GROUP BY C3
```

Comment: what if my first group by is with multiple properties, say Group by C2,C1

Comment: @Jerry what if you try and check what happens? If that is a valid use case, you should have mentioned it before

Comment: I can have multiple where clauses that case, is that an optimal way to achieve this?